# SOLUTION: Android Studio not rendering API 22 activities

Tags: android, android-studio, rendering

I have installed Android Studio a few days ago and if I make a project using an older API than the 22 the IDE is unable to render activities.

I have found that this happens because Android Studio's template of "Blank activity" extends ActionBarActivity in your MainActivity instead of **AppCompatActivity**, which is now deprecated, as shown in the [Android Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html). Just replace it and click "refresh" button in the preview panel.

I have written a new question because I have not found this solution in any of the questions I have seen. Other solutions were just tricks that really did not solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use AppCompatActivity instead of ActionBarActivity.